# Can't pass UIPickerView selection to UITextView in another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uipickerview

I have a UIViewController with a UITextView and UIButton in it. When the user clicks this button it will present a PopUp created with a UIViewController. When the Popup view loads, it displays a UIPickerView.

The problem I am having is passing the selection from the picker to the textView in the first view. I know it has to do with creating global variables, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Anyone could help?

Comment: Without seeing how you've wired it up, my suggestion would be to create a delegate on the popup view controller and execute the delegate method after the user has made a selection. You'll need to implement the delegate method in the calling view controller and use the value that's passed back to populate your UITextView.

Comment: I ama not sure if I understood you, but you think I should set the first ViewController as the delegate of the popup view?

Comment: Yes, define a delegate in the popup view controller with whatever data type (NSString *) you want to pass back from the popup as a parameter. Then implement the delegate methods in the first view controller, taking that parameter to populate the UITextView. You will need to call the delegate method from the popup, after the user selects a value, passing that value as the parameter defined in the delegate definition.

Comment: The part of implementing the methods on the first viewController is alright, but to be honest, how to set a delegate in popup view is what I don't know, can you show me some code?